# Inconsistency in tensorflow 2.0 Model predict and call methods. Call method fails with InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Why does model predict work but model(data) fail in tf 2.0 for the following code?

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers,Input
import tensorflow as tf
input_layer = Input(1)
d1 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(input_layer)
d2 = layers.Dense(3, activation='relu')(d1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=d2)
data = [[1.0]]
print(model.predict(data)) # Works
print(model(data)) # fails with  tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix. Instead it has shape [] [Op:MatMul]
```

Answer (score 1):

**TensorFlow Model** only accepts Tensors when called during **Eager Execution** as indicated in their GitHub repository. 
This is **one** of the lines that were raised when you execute `model(data)`.

```
# Eager execution on data tensors.
        with backend.name_scope(self._name_scope()):
          self._maybe_build(inputs)
          cast_inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
          with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
              self._compute_dtype):
            outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)  # <<< ERROR HERE
          self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
          self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)
```

I converted the **Data variable** you used to predict into a **Tensor Variable**.

See the modified code below:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Input
import tensorflow as tf

input_layer = Input(1)
d1 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(input_layer)
d2 = layers.Dense(3, activation='relu')(d1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=d2)
data = [[1.0]]
print(model.predict(data)) # [[0.02674201 0.         0.        ]]
print(model(tf.Variable(data))) # tf.Tensor([[0.02674201 0.         0.        ]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)
```

You could view the **source code** in TensorFlow [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L81-L2865).